# Video size is 0 bytes using videowriter opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video

The problem what i am facing is that when i try to save the image using Videowriter it creates the video file but the size is 0. I had created a header declaring a function which saves the video and a separate .cpp file which defines the function.When i write the whole code in only one file not in seperate file as before including ViceoCapture and VideoWriter it runs fine and even save the video file with appropriate file size.

When i started to debug i found that every time i receive a frame but VideoWriter.open is null or it says no symbols loaded for opencv_highgui.dll

```
**savevideo.cpp file**
#include"SaveVideo.h"


int CSaveVideo::savevideo()//string InpVideo, int pinstatus)
{
    VideoCapture oVcam(0);


    Mat vFrame;
    string OutPath = "C:\\Users\\20080031\\Desktop\\";
    string Filename = "Vout.avi";
    int vfourcc = CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
    int vfps = 20;
    VideoWriter oVWrite;
    oVWrite.open(Filename, vfourcc, vfps, Size(480, 640), true);

    if (!oVcam.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Camera not opened" << endl;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        oVcam.read(vFrame);
        imshow("Input", vFrame);
        waitKey(1);
        oVWrite.write(vFrame);

    }



}
CSaveVideo::CSaveVideo()
{
    cout << "Inside Constructor" << endl;
}
CSaveVideo::~CSaveVideo()
{
    //VideoCapture Vcam0;
    cout << "Inside Distructor" << endl;
    //Vcam0.release();
}
 **saveVideo.h**
#ifndef SAVEVIDEO_H
#define SAVEVIDEO_H

#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


class CSaveVideo
{
public:
    CSaveVideo();
    ~CSaveVideo();

    //string m_sGPIOpinstatus;
    //char m_cSTOP;

    int savevideo();//string PinStatus, char End,  );
};
#endif SAVEVIDEO_H
**main.cpp**
#include"SaveVideo.h"


int main()
{
    CSaveVideo save;
    save.savevideo();
    /*cout << out<<endl;*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: on a windows system: does your application have access to the opencv_ffmpeg dll file? Please copy it to the application folder or set the PATH variable accordingly. OpenCV will not throw an error if this dll isn't found, but it won't be able to encode videos without it.

Comment: What's your image sizes? I guess it is 640x480 (width x height)? Then you have to change to `Size(640, 480)`

Comment: and you should have some term criteria in your loop. You should close the video file to be sure that the system writes it correctly and players can open it. Try `if(waitKey(1) == 27) break;` followed by a `oVWrite.release();` after he loop. Then press esc during processing to stop and close.

Comment: Thanks Micka it worked.And yes will make those changes suggest by you. Does VideoWriter.write do not resize internally to the incomming frames?

Comment: what was the problem? missing dll?

Comment: The size was wrong

Comment: imho the best way is to capture the first frame and open the videoWriter afterwards, so Size is known instead of hard-coded (or try to use the size property of the stream).

Comment: even if we give any size ?

Comment: you mean that you want to change the size from capturing to some target size? In that case you are right, but you'll have to call cv::resize so that the image in fact does fit the target size! Afaik VideoWriter does not automatically resize the image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better to use this format-

```
VideoWriter oVidWrite;
int nframe_width = oVidCap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int nframe_height = oVidCap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
string str_Path = "video.avi";
int fps = 30;

oVidWrite.open(str_Path, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, Size(nframe_width, nframe_height), true);
```